# How to properly type React context provider

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I feel like I'm doing this all wrong. What is Typescript trying to tell me to do? I'm playing whackamole here

```
TypeScript error in /Users/alex-wilmer/Projects/resideo/pro-portal/packages/web/src/utils/feature-flags/index.tsx(46,9):
Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ OCT19_DEMO: undefined; }>>' is not assignable to type '() => void'.  TS2322

    44 |       value={{
    45 |         flags,
  > 46 |         setFlags,
       |         ^
    47 |       }}>
    48 |       {children}
    49 |     </FeatureFlagsContext.Provider>
```

```
import React, {
  createContext,
  useContext,
  FC,
  useState,
  Dispatch,
  SetStateAction,
} from 'react';

type Flags = {
  OCT19_DEMO: string | undefined;
};

type UseFeatureFlagsValue = {
  flags: Flags;
  setFlags: Dispatch<SetStateAction<{}>>;
};

export const FeatureFlagsContext = createContext({
  flags: { OCT19_DEMO: undefined },
  setFlags: () => {},
});

export const FEATURE_FLAG_PREFIX = 'REACT_APP_FEATURE_FLAG_';

export const FeatureFlagsProvider: FC<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}> = ({ children }): JSX.Element => {
  const [flags, setFlags] = useState(
    Object.entries(process.env).reduce(
      (acc, [key, val]) => {
        if (!key.startsWith(FEATURE_FLAG_PREFIX)) return acc;
        acc[key.replace(FEATURE_FLAG_PREFIX, '')] = val;
        return acc;
      },
      {
        OCT19_DEMO: undefined,
      }
    )
  );

  return (
    <FeatureFlagsContext.Provider
      value={{
        flags,
        setFlags,
      }}>
      {children}
    </FeatureFlagsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useFeatureFlags = (): UseFeatureFlagsValue =>
  useContext(FeatureFlagsContext);
```

Answer (score 2):

`createContext` takes a type parameter, so passing in your type `UseFeatureFlagsValue` fixes the issue:

```
export const FeatureFlagsContext = createContext<UseFeatureFlagsValue>({
  flags: { OCT19_DEMO: undefined },
  setFlags: () => {},
});
```

Do you need to use a default value here? Most of the time you shouldn't need to pass a default value when creating a context (ideally your consumers should be  rendered within a provider which can provide something useful).

[React docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)

> The defaultValue argument is only used when a component does not have
>   a matching Provider above it in the tree. This can be helpful for
>   testing components in isolation without wrapping them. Note: passing
>   undefined as a Provider value does not cause consuming components to
>   use defaultValue.

If you don't need to use a default value, you can create your context with `undefined` using the [Non-Null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
export const FeatureFlagsContext = createContext<UseFeatureFlagsValue>(undefined!);
```